# Extracting text with Beautiful Soup under font size

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I recently started learning python and i want to extract text from a page under

```
<p>
<font size="">
some text</font>
</p>
```

but cant get the text inside font size
Any solution?

Edit: The "some text" changes on refresh that's the problem

Comment: You can use [HTML Parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#examples) from std library.

Comment: In your example, would you like to get the text "some text" or the actual font size ""?

Comment: I want to get the text inside <font size="">this text</font> not the font size

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """<p>
<font size="10">
some text</font>
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

soup.find("font").text        # some text
soup.find("font").get('size') # 10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

b = bs("<p>\
<font size="5">\
some text</font>\
</p>")

b.find("font").attrs["size"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on you specific example, but may need tailoring depending on the real html you need to parse:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""<p>
<font size="">
some text</font>
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('p').text)
```

Comment: Thanks, i changed print(soup.find('p').text) to print(soup.find('font').text) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this!

```
import bs4
import re

data = """
<p>
<font size="">some text</font>
</p>
"""
def striphtml(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return p.sub('', data)

bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
text = bs.find_all('font')
print(striphtml(str(text)))
```

Output : `[some text]`